# Profiling OpenMP: update_cfs_rq_blocked_load takes majority of runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, profiling, openmp

I am profiling some OpenMP code using Intel's **amplxe**. It's giving me some confusing results and I am not sure if something weird is going on with the profiler.
I use `__itt_pause();` and `__itt_resume();` to isolate the OpenMP section of the code, but my bottom-up view looks like this:

```
_raw_spin_lock vmlinux 23.474s
update_cfs_rq_blocked_load vmlinux 15.215s
__schedule vmlinux 10.695s
put_prev_task_fair vmlinux 7.918s
update_cfs_shares vmlinux 7.447s
```

Could this be the effect of overparallelised OpenMP region or is it something weird that my profiler is reporting? I was expecting to see more OpenMP related information in the profiler result, but they are all at the bottom and the runtime is dominated by kernel based routines.

Could someone explain if those are likely things one would see in OpenMP profiles and what exactly do the `cfs` functions do? (My understanding is that... there's a lot of locking going on in the scheduler!?!)

Comment: It's probably just scheduling during busy waiting on a load imbalance. The question here is bad without a [mcve] and specific information about your system, compiler,....  I would strongly recommend using an OpenMP aware performance analysis tool.

Comment: amplxe is OpenMP aware that's why I am not sure. I'm sorry I know the question is bad, but unfortunately I am working on a software which i can't publically disclose parts of. I was hoping to get explanation about what could cause this pattern in the usage.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to create a perfectly innocent [mcve] from proprietary code - it just does take some effort. On the other hand discussing a complex performance issue based on 5 lines of stack trace is impossible.

Comment: If my concern was a specific function that would not be difficult. If my concern was a specific function I can of course run it in isolation, but there's complex interaction going on in the background which makes that impossible. I am just asking what the scheduling bits do and if anyone has seen them when profiling OpenMP.

Comment: It shouldn't be beyond the wit of man to tell us more than you have. You haven't told us which compiler you're using, how big your machine is, how many threads you're using, how long the total run is (does the ~65s here represent 1% of the total time or 90%?), or whether you have set any thread affinity. All of those are potentially useful. (You didn't bother to tell us that you're running on Linux either, but we can deduce that).

Comment: I can't take you what percentage of my runtime this section is, because it's not accurate compared to my wall clock timers. I can't disclose the architecture I am running on because it's not publicly available, but you can assume supercomputer setting. The only thing i can disclose is that the number of threads is in the 400s. Sorry. I am aware that the question is vague but this is all I am allowed to disclose. I can't disclose the workload, the hardware or the software beyond that.